# \cite with large number of citekeys

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have a .sty file for my latex document where I create bibliography category (see[1] below).  I have these lines in my document and it worked:

```
\addtocategory{papers}{sushil}
```

But in this way I have to add citekey by hand for a large number of articles. So I have been suggested to use this:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
   \ifentrytype{article}{%
     \iffieldundef{journaltitle}{%
       \addtocategory{subpapers}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
       }{%
         \addtocategory{papers}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
       }{%
           }%
       } 
  }
```

Which I guess is same thing but does things automatically. But this case does not work if I do not use `\cite{sushil}` which again brings me to the same point that I have to add citekeys by hand for a large number of articles. I thought that `\nocite{*}` could work but I already have `\nocite{*}` in my `.sty` file.

Does anyone knows how to solve this? I do not want to add so many citekeys by hand as its quite time taking.

---

[1]

From my .sty file:

```
% Bibliography categories
\def\makebibcategory#1#2{\DeclareBibliographyCategory{#1}\defbibheading{#1}{\section*{#2}}}
\makebibcategory{papers}{Refereed Research Papers}
\makebibcategory{subpapers}{Submitted Papers to Journals and arXiv}


\setlength{\bibitemsep}{2.65pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{.8cm}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}

\renewcommand*{\bibitem}{\addtocounter{papers}{1}\item \mbox{}\hskip-0.85cm\hbox to 0.85cm{\hfill\arabic{papers}.~~}}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list{}
  {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
   \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
   \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endlist}
{\bibitem}

\newenvironment{publications}{\section{\LARGE Publications}\label{papersstart}\vspace*{0.2cm}\small
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1.5ex}{1ex}\itemsep=0.00cm
}{\label{papersend}\addtocounter{sumpapers}{-1}\refstepcounter{sumpapers}\label{sumpapers}}

\def\printbib#1{\printbibliography[category=#1,heading=#1]\lastref{sumpapers}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are using biber as the backend and then you can add this automatically as biber reads your .bib file by putting this in your biber.cfg:

```
<sourcemap>
  <maps datatype="bibtex">
    <map final="true">
      <per_type>ARTICLE</per_type>
      <map_step map_field_source="JOURNAL/>
      <map_step map_field_set="KEYWORDS" map_field_value="subpapers"/>
    </map>
    <map>
      <per_type>ARTICLE</per_type>
      <map_step map_field_set="KEYWORDS" map_field_value="subpapers"/>
    </map>
  </maps>
</sourcemap>
```

Or, if you are using the biblatex 2.0 and biber 1.0 betas, you can also do this on a per-document basis in your preamble:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldsource=journal, final=true]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={papers}]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={subpapers}]
    }
  }
}
```

You can then simply filter on keywords with `\printbibliography[keyword=papers]` etc.

Comment: what package I need to add to my .tex file to use \DeclareSourcemap ??

Comment: It's part of biblatex 2.0 which is on SourceForge but is not released yet to TexLive. I hope it will be released in a week or so. It's easy to install manually though. You must be using biber 1.0 too - this feature relies on biber.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the help and infor. I will wait till it released. But do you know is there a way to add many keys to the following command: \addtocategory{papers}{key1,key2}. For 2 keys its fine but when dealing with 1000 keys its difficult to add them.

Comment: The sourcemap functionality is already in 1.7/0.9.9, but only via biber's config file. See the biber manual - you can do the same thing using the biber.conf file using biber's XML options format. It's only the LaTeX macro interface to this which has been added in 2.0. I wouldn't try to create a category like this - just add keywords using sourcemap and then filter on keywords instead of a category.

Comment: Could you please point me to the installation link.  Thanks a lot once again.   Sushil

Comment: just forgot to mentione that I already have 2011 TexLive installed

Comment: Biber is here: (http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/1.0/)

BibLaTeX is here: (http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/biblatex-2.0/)

Neither are in TL 2011 - they are much later than the first TL 2011 release.

Comment: I am using Texshop to run my .tex file. I added this line to use biber \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} and then run it in usual way. It give error that: "Option clash for package biblatex". I am using a .sty file for my document. What could cause this?  I check I am using --verion 1.0 of biber.  Thanks-Sushil

Comment: update: I soved the above problme as I was using usepackage command at two places. Removing one of them make the above error go away. But now I see it complaints about \DeclareSourcemap as undefined control sequence. I have a biber.conf file in my /Library/biber/ area.     Sushil

Comment: If it complains about \DeclareSourcemap, it must mean that you are loading an older version. If you put `\listfiles` at the beginning of the document, what version of biblatex does it say you are loading?

Comment: This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2011) , so that means I have to update to version 2.0....

Comment: opps i think what i wrote is BibTex and not Biblatex...how to know the veriosn of biblatex as I am using TexLive2011

Comment: I thin you are write I am using v1.5 from the lines of log file:(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2011/06/08 v1.5 programmable bibliographies
--- So I need to update it to 2.0

Comment: Yes, 1.5 is very old now. You need biblatex 2.0 and biber 1.0. Forget bibtex, the version of that is irrelevant as you won't be using it if you want to use sourcemapping.

Comment: Is there an easy way to install new version of 2.0 in TexLive2011? I find various post but not sure of all the steps.  sushil

Comment: It will be easy when TL 2012 comes out soon as it will be available via the package manager. Until then, you would need to get the TDS 2.0 release from SourceForge and just copy the files over your existing ones or put them somewhere kpsewhich finds before the TL 2011 install. I would ask a separate question about this if you need to.

Comment: Your example files work for me - you had a typo in the \DeclareSourcemap macro where you said "fieldset=keyword" instead of "fieldset=keywords" ...

Comment: It still does not work for me. I mean it produce pdf file without and error but I do not see two article in the pdffile. May I aske How you run my example file? I run them using TexShop editor.

Comment: OK, I first run biber mDocument.tex and then texshop and I see the two listed articles but they comes with subpapepers only ....So I am missing the last piece why paper category do not show ....did it shows in your run? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have edited the DeclareSourcemap command in the answer. Now it works for me. One has to remember that Sourcemap works on the raw .bib and so if you are using "JOURNAL" instead of "JOURNALTITLE", then that's what you must match on.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works perfectly :) . I really appreciate your help and time. Thanks again. -sushil

Comment: Hi Again, I was trying to play with more with biber. I have a second .bib file which has some articles. Now I want to include this new .bib file to my list but as the same time I want to make sure I do not list the same entries which are already in this file. Is it possible...could someone tell me the syntax to be used in above \DecalreSourcemap command....thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like the following line do the work:                              `\bibliography{myMainPub,myPub}      
    
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
   \map{ 
      \perdatasource{myMainPub.bib}
       \pertype{article}
         \step[fieldsource=journal, final=true]
        \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={mainpapers}]
       }
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldsource=journal, final=true]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={papers}]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={subpapers}]
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to add some extra information to the bib file you could add an `entrysubtype` field with papers\subpapers. Then `\nocite{*}` coupled with `\printbibliography[subtype=papers]` or possibly easier `\printbibliography[notsubtype=subpapers]`

Answer (score 1):

No I have this example where I want to add citekeys in an automated way to \cite{} command instead of writing them by hand. Because I am dealing with >500 entries in my bib file and its difficult to add them by hand.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{articlepublished}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{articleunpublished}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%
    \iffieldundef{journaltitle}{%
      \addtocategory{articleunpublished}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
    }{%
      \addtocategory{articlepublished}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
    }%
  }{%
  }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{AX12,
      author         = "Authors1",
      title          = "{Ttile of articles}",
      collaboration  = "Collaboration",
      year           = "2012",
}
@article{AY11,
      author         = "Authors2",
      title          = "{Ttile of articles}",
      collaboration  = "Collaboration",
      year           = "2011",
      journal        = "Phys.Lett.",  
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{AX12,AY11}

\printbibliography[category=articlepublished,title={Published Articles}]

\printbibliography[category=articleunpublished,title={Unpublished Articles}]

\end{document}
```